# Select Multiple Fields from one block and move to another using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Can any one please help in doing this using Jquery. Where I need to select the values from the left block and move to right block when Arrow button is pressed. As shown in the screen shot.[image]

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

New Document

```
function moveRight(){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#myserversID option:selected").appendTo("#myserversID1")

    });

}

function moveLeft(){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#myserversID1 option:selected").appendTo("#myserversID")

    });
}
```

```
<option value="one">one</option>

<option value="two">two</option>

<option value="three">three</option>

<option value="four">four</option>

<option value="five">five</option>

<option value="six">six</option>
```

Comment: Have you done any scripting for this? I mean did you try anything for achieving this?

Comment: thats one really fancy graphic

Comment: Yes, I have Scripted for this..But I am not getting the button in the middle of the two blocks.

Comment: I recommend you, using a list instead of a select. This way, you could easily move the whole list (`ul` > all `li` children) or only selected ones. Then, append your selected items to left, or right. The behaviour of append, or prepend, is to create a new element if it not allready exists, otherwise, it just move it !